# How to show/hide SharePoint columns based on the dropdown input?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have this code on SharePoint script editor. There is a dropdown with Yes/No option and based on the user input I want to show or hide these col 1-6 fields. For example, if user says 'Yes' then I want to show col 1-6 fields and if they later decides to say 'No' then I want to hide col 1-6 fields. I tried every single thing

I have tried many different options by separating each column in separate editor, I can hide them by default but when I say 'Yes' all the fields shows up but when I say 'No' only last field (col 6) get hide.

```js
<script language="javascript"></script>
<script>
// wait for the window to load
$(window).load(function () {
   // EXAMPLE: Set the value of the Title field to Hello world!
   SPUtility.GetSPField('abcdef').MakeReadOnly();
   SPUtility.GetSPField('abcdef').MakeReadOnly();
   SPUtility.GetSPField('abcdef').MakeReadOnly(); 
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 1');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 2');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 3');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 4');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 5');   
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 6');
   
$(App.Dropdown).on(change(function()) {
    var App = SPUtility.GetSPField('---Dropdown Column Name---');
    var AppValue = App.GetValue();
    if (AppValue === 'No'){
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 1');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 2');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 3');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 4');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 5');   
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 6');
 }
   else{
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 1');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 2');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 3');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 3');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 4');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 5');
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 1').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 2').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 3').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 4').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 5').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 6').SetValue("No");
 }
});

</script>
```

Now, using the code above all the fields (col 1-6) are showing up by default.

Comment: Is there any updates ? If the reply below is helpful to this question, please accept as answer so that it could also help others in the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dropdown choice field named "TestDropDown" and modify the code snippet as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() {
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 1');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 2');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 3');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 4');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 5');   
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 6');

  $("select[title='TestDropDown']").change(function() {
    var App = SPUtility.GetSPField('TestDropDown');
    var AppValue = App.GetValue();
    if (AppValue === 'No'){
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 1');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 2');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 3');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 4');
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 5');   
   SPUtility.HideSPField('Col Name 6');
 }
   else{
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 1');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 2');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 3');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 3');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 4');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Col Name 5');
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 1').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 2').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 3').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 4').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 5').SetValue("No");
    SPUtility.GetSPField('Col Name 6').SetValue("No");
 }
 });


});


</script>
```

Select No, all fileds hidden:

[image]

Change to Yes, all fields show:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was just missing the 'select' function within the code.

Comment: @ArifKhan,yes, I changed the select change function in the code snippet above.
And if the reply is helpful to you, You can accept as answer so that it could help others who stuck with the similiar question in the forum.